# XML validation against external schemas

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

How to validate a XML file against all schemas defined in that XML file?

I'm searching for a local way not using an online service. This should be done by a tool or in Java code.

For example I have a XML file starting with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mets:mets xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/METS/ https://www.loc.gov/standards/mets/version112/mets.xsd http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-6.xsd http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink https://www.w3.org/XML/2008/06/xlink.xsd">
```

And the validator must validate the XML file against the XSD files defined in xsi:schemaLocation.

I've tried some basic tools but they seem to perform a syntax check only.

Comment: Tell us what you're doing, and then we can tell you what you are doing wrong. If you're in Java, use the JAXP Java API to invoke the built-in schema validator in the JDK, or you can also use the Saxon s9api API if you want XSD 1.1 capability.

Comment: I've found a solution. Apache Xerces provides a way to validate all that. I can now validate from inside my program using Xerces-J (Java) and use the simple Perl validation script (from Xerces-P). The main feature to use seems to be "validation/schema-full-checking" and "honour-all-schemaLocations". Really great.